# Converting keynote presentations to images on the ipad

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, keynote

I'd like to be able to read keynote presentation files on the ipad, and convert them to a series of images, one per slide.  Is there an easy way of doing this?  I briefly took a look at the internals of a keynote presentation, and the huge xml wad looks pretty daunting.  Is there a library that can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a [web service](http://blog.slideshare.net/2008/12/05/you-can-now-upload-keynote-files-to-slideshare/) that converts on-demand may help you.

Comment: That's a good idea, hadn't thought of doing this server side, though it's an obvious fit.

Answer (score 0):

You mean besides using Export > Images?

Comment: Sorry, I meant programmatically, ie, a library.